# How to highlight the selected item in the dropdown list of Picker in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I'm using the Picker component of react native and want to apply CSS like background color for the selected item in the dropdown list of **Picker**.

below is my code snippet:

```
                    <Text style={clStyle.schoolNameLabel}>School Board*</Text>
                    <Picker
                        mode="dropdown"
                        itemStyle={clStyle.schoolNamePickerStyle}
                        style={clStyle.schoolNamePickerStyle}
                        placeholder="Select"
                        selectedValue={values.board_id}
                        onValueChange={(value) => {
                            handleSchoolBoardChange(value, setFieldTouched, handleChange);
                        }}
                        enabled={schools && schools.length > 0 ? false : true}
                    >
                        <Picker.Item label="Select" color="#ccc" value="" />
                        {updateBoardDropdown()}
                    </Picker>

updateBoardDropdown = () => {
    try {
        const all_items =
            this.props.metaData &&
            this.props.metaData.boardResponse &&
            this.props.metaData.boardResponse.length > 0 &&
            this.props.metaData.boardResponse.map((_board: BoardResponse, i: number) => {
                return (
                    <Select.Item
                        key={_board.id}
                        backgroundColor="yellow"
                        color="red"
                        label={_board.name}
                        value={_board.id.toString()}
                    />
                );
            });
        return all_items;
    } catch (e) {
        SentryException({
            property: ' ~ file: create-lead-screen.tsx ~ line 674 ~ CreateLead ~ e',
            message: e as Error,
        });
    }
};
```

Please help Thanks

Comment: share updateBoardDropdown code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `updateBoardDropdown` add check of `values.board_id== _board.id` like

```
<Select.Item
    key={_board.id}
    backgroundColor="yellow"
    color="red"
    label={_board.name}
    value={_board.id.toString()}/>
```

to

```
<Select.Item
    key={_board.id}
    backgroundColor={values.board_id== _board.id ? "grey":"yellow"}
    color="red"
    label={_board.name}
    value={_board.id.toString()}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dropdown from native-base and here is the code.

```
import { NativeBaseProvider, Select } from 'native-base';
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import { hp, wp } from '../constants/scaling';
import { colors, fonts } from '../constants/theme';
import selectStyles from '../styles/selectStyles';
import { textStyles } from '../styles/textStyles';
const CustomDropDownInput = ({ label, placeholder, data, value, setValue }) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', height: hp(12) }}>
            <NativeBaseProvider>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        ...textStyles.Label,
                        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                        alignSelf: 'flex-start'
                    }}>
                    {label}
                </Text>

                <Select
                    useNativeDriver={true}
                    selectedValue={value}
                    minWidth={wp(96)}
                    accessibilityLabel={placeholder}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255,255,255,1)'}
                    _item={selectStyles._item}
                    customDropdownIconProps={{
                        color: '#fff',
                        marginRight: wp(3)
                    }}
                    _selectedItem={selectStyles._selectedItem}
                    mt={1}
                    borderWidth={0}
                    borderRadius={0}
                    h={hp(7)}
                    backgroundColor={colors.inputBgColor}
                    fontFamily={fonts.Medium}
                    color={'#fff'}
                    fontSize={RFValue(14)}
                    borderBottomColor={'#fff'}
                    borderBottomWidth={1}
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#0000',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }}
                    onValueChange={itemValue => setValue(itemValue)}>
                    {data.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Select.Item
                                label={item.label}
                                value={item.value}
                                key={`${index}`}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </Select>
            </NativeBaseProvider>
        </View>
    );
};

const compareProps = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    if (prevProps == nextProps) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
export default memo(CustomDropDownInput, compareProps);
```

here are the selectStyles.js file

```
import {Icon} from 'native-base';
import React from 'react';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import {RFValue} from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {wp} from '../constants/scaling';
import {colors, fonts} from '../constants/theme';
const selectStyles = {
  _item: {
    pt: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 2 : 2,
    pb: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 2 : 2,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderBottomColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.1)',
    _text: {
      includeFontPadding: false,
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontFamily: fonts.Medium,
      fontSize: RFValue(13),
      color: colors.textPrimaryColor,
    },
  },
  _selectedItem: {
    bg: colors.primaryColor,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    _text: {
      includeFontPadding: false,
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontSize: RFValue(13),
      textAlignVertical: 'center',
      fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
      color: '#fff',
    },
    endIcon: (
      <Icon as={Entypo} name={'check'} size={wp(5)} color={colors.white} />
    ),
  },
};

export default selectStyles;
```